# How do two inline block elements influence each other alignment

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

If we have two elements next to each other with display as `inline-block`, the bigger block (in terms of height) is the one which appears to influence the position of the other one when vertical-align is set for either of two.

How does it actually work? How can we think of a line on which an element will reside and when the vertical align is changed, we may just think it’s moving with respect to that line. Somehow I’m unable to understand why the other element also appear to move.

I'll illustrate with some examples. So Going through this
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273016/why-is-this-inline-inline-block-inline-flex-inline-grid-element-pushed-downward) (with which this question has been marked duplicate) I did understand the the first div sets the baseline of the inline-block. for e,g in the following code, gjpiy sets the baseline and the other two inline-block divs that follow after that reside *above* this line.

```css
.first, .second{
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
 }
 
 .first{
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
 }

 .second{
    height: 30px;
    background: yellow;
  }
  
  .simpleDiv{
   display: inline-block
  }
```

```html
<div class="simpleDiv">gjpiy</div>
<div class="first"></div>

<div class="second"></div>
```

But my questions are different.
Now here're my question:

1. If you change the `vertical-align` to the bigger div, all of the three blocks appear to move up.

   ```css
   .first, .second{
       width: 100px;
       display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .first{
       height: 100px;
       background: red;
       vertical-align:top;
    }

    .second{
       height: 30px;
       background: yellow;
     }
   ```

   ```html
   <div style="display: inline-block">gjpiy</div>
   <div class="first"></div>

   <div class="second"></div>
   ```
2. If you change the `vertical-align` of the second div (the smaller one) only that goes up.

```css
.first, .second{
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
 }
 
 .first{
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
 }

 .second{
    height: 30px;
    background: yellow;
    vertical-align:top;
  }
```

```html
<div style="display:inline-block">gjpiy</div>
<div class="first"></div>

<div class="second"></div>
```

So this is what I mean by the bigger element *seems to influence* Can anyone please clarify?

Comment: I've read your sentence, "How can we benchmark a line on which an element will reside and when the vertical align is changed, we may just think it’s moving with respect to that line." three times and don't understand what you're asking

Comment: What I meant was there’s a probably a line (baseline) above and below which an element  moves depending upon what vertical-align we set we set for it. What’s unclear to me how does the other element that resides adjacent to it appears to move. It always turns out the one with greater height seems to influence.

Comment: Don't add comments, edit the question to enhance clarity please.  Perhaps when you say "How does it actually work?" specifically say what "it" refers to - is IT here vertical alignment, something else? Strive to make everything concise and non-ambiguous.

Comment: "gjpiy sets the baseline" - I see no baseline with that code block: ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align#baseline  Perhaps I misunderstand your reference in relationship to the parent elements baseline? (body in the first example)

Comment: Perhaps this reference can help: The baseline of an 'inline-block' is the baseline of its last line box in the normal flow, unless it has either no in-flow line boxes or if its 'overflow' property has a computed value other than 'visible', in which case the baseline is the bottom margin edge. ref: from https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align scroll down to the bottom of the section.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an "answer" per se but does illustrate where you see spans with `inline-block` with and without content text (forced as `&nbsp;`) also come into play here.  The first three all have content; the last two the same layout as 2/3 but no content text.

- This reference is useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17337172/125981
- For a visual as is this helps: [Why does this inline-block element have content that is not vertically aligned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12950479/why-does-this-inline-block-element-have-content-that-is-not-vertically-aligned)
- Another:
  [CSS - Display text at descent instead of baseline?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6178506/125981)

As does the specification reference from my comment here: (scroll down to the bottom of the section.) https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align

MDN flow discusssion reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_flow_layout/Block_and_inline_layout_in_normal_flow  Includes some links to the BLOCK and INLINE BLOCK also at the bottom.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #00FFFF;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}

body * {
  line-height: 1em;
}

.block-me {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 1px #0000FF;
}

.first,
.second {
  width: 100px;
}

.first {
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.second {
  height: 30px;
  background: yellow;
}

.block-meX.line-rules {
  width: 90vw;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #FF00FF;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 1px;
}

.block-meX.line-rules:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 70vw;
  height: 1px;
  border-color: #00FF00;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  margin-top: -6em;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-me">gjpiy</div>
<div class="block-me first">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="block-me second">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="block-me first"></div>
<div class="block-me second"></div>
<hr class="line-rules block-meX"></hr>
<hr class="line-rules block-meX"></hr>
```

Comment: Yeah I did observe the behavior is different with and without content in the divs. But this adds even more confusion if we try thinking of a consistent rule that will be followed for the baseline with respect to which the elements should be moving.